# Javascript Array, find and combine entries with duplicate values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following dynamically generated array:

```
var myArray = ("0% { left:74px; top:202px; }"   , "44% { left:427px; top:122px; }", "0% { font-size:11px; }", "55% { font-size:49px; }" );
```

There are 2 entries that have the same start value: 0%. How can I find this and combine it together:

```
form:
0% { left:74px; top:202px; },
0% { font-size:11px; },
to
0% { left:74px; top:202px; font-size:11px;},
```

Thank you

Edited the code to a valid array.

Comment: Is that a valid javascript array ?

Comment: this is a part from my array. Should be valid with []

Comment: there was a point between 55 and {. I had removed that. the array should be valid

Comment: It's still not a valid array.

Comment: What's that XX % thing? Is that some of animation or something?

Comment: Yes, its a css animation propriety.

Comment: there were some points left after 44 and 55. The original values were 44.45354333443543 so I just put 44 but I forgotten the. Is the array valid now?

Comment: nothing in your post even vaguely resembles a javascript array.  An array is wrapped in parens ()  not curly braces, in javascript.  You have something that vaguely looks like a JSON object, but it's not that either.

Comment: @Dr. Dredel no, an array is expressed with square brackets, not parentheses. His array definitely **is** an array. In particular it's an array with a single string in it.

Comment: @Mircea the contents of that array is just that one single string. If you want to break up the contents of the string, the first thing you're going to have to do is transform it into something *else*. If you're *generating* the array with server-side code, then the right thing to do is generate the appropriate data structure and *then* start working on it. (In fact I don't know why you wouldn't eliminate duplicates before generating the Javascript.)

Comment: @Pointy, he revised his code after I made that comment.

Comment: @Dr Dredel - ah I see; sorry for not checking first!

Comment: @pointy also, I was referring to the Array() constructor which takes the list between the parens when initiated. i.e. var foo = new Array(1,2,3);   It looks to me like Mircea is a beginner so I was offering the most basic Array declaration methodology.

Comment: OK, well in my personal opinion the Array constructor is a bad idea - the semantics are confused and the ambiguity of constructing an array with just one numeric element is resolved in a way most people wouldn't expect.

Comment: @Dr Dredel and anyway, he's changed it again, so that now it's neither an array nor an object literal - it's just a string constant :-)

Comment: @Mircea - you should really slow down and consult a Javascript reference book, or some online basic resources.  Javascript is a real programming language, and it turns out that you actually have to learn the syntax in order to work effectively with it. What you've got as of now is an expression that'll evaluate to the last string in that comma-separated list of strings.  It's not an array at all, and it's not an object literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh, I see.. you're printing your array and this is what you're getting, right?

In that case...

```
for(var i =0; i< myArray.length ; i++){
  for(var j=i+1; j<myArray.length;j++){
      if(i == j) continue;
      if(myArray[i].substring(0,3) == myArray[j].substring(0,3)){//found matching first 2 chars
         myArray[i] = myArray[i].substring(0,3) + myArray[j].replace(/\{(.*?)\}/,"$1 ;") + myArray[i].substring(4);

        myArray.splice(j--,1);//remove the doup and decrease the counter so you don't skip one now that the array is shorter

      }
  }
}
```

I didn't test this, but something to this effect :)

Oh.. you edited.  What you have now is definitely not an array... but you're closer than you were before.

I think array is a reserved word...

```
var myArray = ("0% { left:74px; top:202px; }"   , "44% { left:427px; top:122px; }", "etc", "etc" );
```

Comment: Sorry, the code have an error. I can't tell why... I can make my array like this: var myArray = ("0% { left:74px; top:202px; }", "44% { left:427px; top:122px; }", "etc", "etc" );

Comment: my code might have bugs, but it's what you should do in theory... first make your array look right (as I show at the bottom of my answer). Then loop through the array looking for matches on the first few characters and merge them together and then splice out the duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

That is an array literal with only one member.  You need to end the strings between the commas to separate the members.   I would try to rewrite each member as an object literal and use json methods to alternate between string and object.   In object form, you can do a mixin to merge the like members.